# How to export a single WhatsApp chat?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger

I'm trying to export the *complete* chat between a user on WhatsApp. I have tried using the "Email Chat" option, but it seems this feature does not export the complete conversation. I believe it has some sort of size limit. I experimented with several large conversations (dating back to 2 year ago) - they should definitely be 4 MB+ in file size when exported, but when I export them via Gmail, the file size is always 2 MB. The messages before that are ignored.

I also tried using web.whatsapp.com and scrolling upwards using iMacros and then selecting the text using jQuery  but that is proving to be difficult. Browser crashes after a certain point.

I don't believe the database backups in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/` are of any use - they're heavily encrypted.

Any interesting work-arounds or solutions?

Comment: The only solution I could think of, would be to manually pull the unencrypted database from WhatsApp's data folder, and filter it with a thrown-together tool. Unfortunately, this requires root access.

Comment: Do you mean the text file it creates before attaching to an email conversation? Yes, it definitely requires root access, but I'm open to ideas. If it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement**: rooted device.

Download [WA Tweaks](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/alex193a/wa-tweaks-for-whatsapp/) and install it. 
Close WhatsApp process, open WA Tweaks inside the WATweaks App and there you would find a "Conversation" tab. Load conversation.  As your chat sizes are huge it may take alot of time. From there you can get complete conversation backed up / emailed.

You can see demo video of the app [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzY9GmM_ZfY) on my channel. 
This should solve your issue. If you have a low end phone it will get stuck.